# I have no transitive dependencies when use custom jar file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, jar

I have created own .jar file using maven. It requires some libs. All of them are added in pom.xml of custom .jar, but I have a problem! When i adding my jar to project no required libs are adding to Maven Dependencies of project. And i dont want to create jar with dependencies. I belive that it is bad solution to download all required libs in jar. I am new to maven, so please help to find solution.This is the pom.xml of my jar:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ReportBuilder</groupId>
    <artifactId>ReportBuilder</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ReportBuilder</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Yes i have next exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/exception/VelocityException

Comment: What do you mean by "When i adding my jar to project". Do you manually add it or do you add it as regular maven dependency? Can you pleas add the pom.xml of your second project.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax
<dependency>
  <groupId>ReportBuilder</groupId>
  <artifactId>ReportBuilder</artifactId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/src/libs/ReportBuilder-0.0.1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't you have a dependency to your ReportBuilder POM instead of your ReportBuilder JAR?

Comment: You should run 'mvn install' in your ReportBuilder project and then there will be no need to specify the systemPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current specification, using `<scope>system</scope>` and specifying the path to the `jar` file, you only include a single jar without any dependencies. Maven cannot know about dependencies because the jar file itself does not contain this information and maven cannot access `pom.xml` (that was used to build the jar file) via this configuration.

Transitive dependencies can only be resolved, if maven has access to dependency information specified in `pom.xml` of the dependent jar. To make it accessible, you need to install the dependent project into you local maven repository (located in `~/.m2/repository`). You can achieve this by using maven goal `install`. For example:

```
mvn -DskipTests clean install
```

The goal `install` is executed after `package` and will copy the built jar file and dependency meta information (extracted from `pom.xml`) into your local maven repository.

After you have installed your dependent project, you can include it into any other project like a regular dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ReportBuilder</groupId> 
  <artifactId>ReportBuilder</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven looks up all dependencies in local repository. As you installed it, maven will find it -- including information about transitive dependencies which can be resolved now.

Comment: As i know maven imports all required libs. If A dependet from B and C uses A, then C project should automatically add all required for A libs. We dont need to add all B project dependencies. Am i  wrong? I dont very like this solution, coz lib's weight increase in times. It is not very comfortable. And when i add net.masterthought dependency to pom.xml maven imports a number of libs (10 or 15 jars). I whant to have such situation with my own jar

Comment: Thank you! It is exactly what i was looking for